# How to fix Cannot find an object with Identity in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get this Powershell script to transfer group membership from one user to another in Active Directory. I am getting the error below stating it can't find the object with identity. This is odd because the user is in AD in the domain that I called upon and the first user that I am transferring the membership from is found without any issues. Any ideas?

```
Get-ADUser -server "ngcore01.test.hawaii.local" -Identity user11 -Properties memberof |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof
Add-ADGroupMember -Member user22
```

This is the error:

> Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'user22' under: 'DC=test,DC=hawaii,DC=local'.
>   At line:3 char:1
>   + Add-ADGroupMember -Members user22
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (user22:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory. 
>      Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Comment: On mobile but I think it’s -Members (plural), have you tried that?

Comment: As Matt said the Add-ADGroupMember has -Members and not -Member. That is the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that the `Add-ADGroupMember` cmdlet has difficulties finding a **group** with Identity `user22` and that is because you do not supply this Identity value. (See: [Add-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps))

The `memberof` property returned by `Get-ADUser` is a **collection** of DistinguishedNames of the user’s direct group membership and you need to loop over the returned values in this collection to use as `-Identity` parameter on the call to `Add-ADGroupMember`

Try

```
(Get-ADUser -Server "ngcore01.test.hawaii.local" -Identity user11 -Properties memberof).memberof | ForEach-Object {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members user22
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i'm a complete novice. So the -Identity is calling upon the identity from the top(user11) and copying  over all over memberships to user 22? Is that how that last command will work?

Comment: @ITHawaii1990 Yes, The `-Identity` on the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet ensures you get the group memberof collection of _user11_, which is a set of (distinghuished) group names. The `Add-ADGroupMember` also has an `-Identity` parameter and there you give it the identity of each _group_ that user11 is in. It then adds user22 to all of these these groups.